# How to obtain the boolean expression from a 4 input K-Map

Tags: boolean, logic

I noticed the 4 input K-map is read differently from a 3 input K-map.

I am assuming the A, not A, B, not B, C , not C , D and not D are located differently in a 4 input K-Map.

[image: 4 Input K Map]

Can anyone explain where these locations are located on a 4 input K map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) about Karnaugh map in Wikipedia. This is layout of map for 4 variables:
 [K-map for 4 variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aK-map_minterms_A.svg).